# send post request having basic auth and payload data without any external library

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a script in secured environment , hence unable to download 'requests'. I want to fire a post request which has some payload data , headers and basic auth security. I have searched lot and couldn't find any approach to do it. If anyone has some references , kindly answer.

Comment: Here are [some examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) from Python's standard library. Scroll down for how to add basic auth. Scroll up to see how the API works. It's confusing stuff, so if you figure it out, I'd appreciate if you answer your own question with a "cleaned (no real passwords)" example.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for reply . I will look into it .